# Java SpringBootTest EntityNotFoundException on setup method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

There is a class for test to save some constraints, there is method `setup` with @Before annotation, where test data is saved in database:

.. And when running the test in this method, there is an EntityNotFoundException error when saving `Entity` to the repository:

```java
    
    . . .

    @Autowired
    EntityFeatureConfigRepository entityFeatureConfigRepository;

    @Autowired
    FeatureRepository featureRepository;

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        entityRepository.deleteAll();
        featureRepository.deleteAll();
        entityFeatureConfigRepository.deleteAll();
        
        featureRepository.save(new Feature(1);                    <==== 1L - id 
        entityRepository.save(new Entity(1));
        entityFeatureConfigRepository.save(new EntityFeatureConfig( <=EXCEPTION
                new Feature(1),          
                new Entity(1),
                true));
    }
    . . .
```

```
Unable to find Entity with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Entity with id 1
```

The error is that `Entity` does not exist, **although it is saved in the `setup` method**

If there are such fields in the class `EntityFeatureConfig`, maybe the problem is in them.

```java
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "feature_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Feature feature;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Entity entity;
```

And `Entity`

```java
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "entity")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<UserManagingEntity> user;
```

What can this error be related to,
that the data is not in the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use returned objects from save method instead of create new ones

```
Feature f = featureRepository.save(new Feature(1);                 
Entity e = entityRepository.save(new Entity(1));
```